# Regex to match number not preceeded by alphabets

Tags: php, regex

I want to get first number from the string before the word 'minimum', preceeded by a space and not succeeded by '-'. Example:

- shouldn't match the words 2-3, TT-89 etc; (ie, a number followed by - and another number or alphabets followed by - and numbers)
- should match the word 2-rolls (ie, a number followed by - and alphabets)

I'm trying with the following code:

```
$str = "Red  QQ-4555 White  TT-789 Yellow Minimum order applies. This is a test";
$explodeByMinimumArray = preg_split("/minimum/i", str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), ' ', $str));   
preg_match_all('/\d+(?!-\d)/', $explodeByMinimumArray[0], $numberFromStringBeforeMinimumArray);  
print_r($numberFromStringBeforeMinimumArray);
```

This is returning `$numberFromStringBeforeMinimumArray` as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4555 
            [1] => 789
        )

)
```

But the expected output is empty as QQ-4555 and TT-789 are preceeded by some characters.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [`'~(?<![\p{L}\d]-)\b\d+(?!-\d)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/yNh1Lb/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind to ensure you do not match digits that are preceded with a letter/digit and a `-`:

```
(?<![\p{L}\d]-|\d)\d+(?!-\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNh1Lb/4).

**Details**

- `(?<![\p{L}\d]-|\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a letter or digit followed with `-` or a single digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?!-\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `-` and then a digit immediately to the right of the current location

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Red  QQ-4555 White  TT-789 123 Yellow Minimum order applies. This is a test ";
$explodeByMinimumArray = preg_split("/minimum/i", str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), ' ', $str));   
preg_match_all('/\s+\d+(?!-\d)/', $explodeByMinimumArray[0], $numberFromStringBeforeMinimumArray);  
print_r($numberFromStringBeforeMinimumArray);
```

will give

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  123
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex using multiple lookaround assertions:

```
(?<=\s)\d+\b(?!-\d+)(?=.*Minimum)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nh1Dux/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\s)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we have a whitespace at previous position
- `\d+\b`: Match 1+ digits followed by word boundary assertion
- `(?!-\d+)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `-<digits>` ahead
- `(?=.*Minimum)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `Minimum` text ahead